Confusion about finding a dual basis
Given a basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ of $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, I am to find the dual basis.
I am sure that finding each dual basis functional $v_i^*$ ($i=1,2,3$) involves solving the linear system (where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta and $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is the vector of coefficients that determines $v_i^*$) $$\begin{cases} v_i^*(v_1)=\lambda_i^T v_1=\delta_{i1} \\ v_i^*(v_2)=\lambda_i^T v_2=\delta_{i2} \\ v_i^*(v_3)=\lambda_i^T v_3=\delta_{i3} \end{cases}$$ for $\lambda_i$. However, using

If $E$ is a vector space of finite dimension $n$ and $(u_1,\dotsc,u_n)$ is a basis of $E$, for any linear form $f^*\in E^*$, for every $x=x_1u_1+\dotsb+x_nu_n\in E$, by linearity we have $$\begin{align*}f^*(x)&=f^*(u_1)x_1+\dotsb+f^*(u_n)x_n\\&=\lambda_1x_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nx_n,\end{align*}$$ with $\lambda_i=f^*(u_i)\in K$ [the underlying field] for every $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$. Thus, with respect to the basis $(u_1,\dotsc, u_n)$, the linear form $f^*$ is represented by the row vector $$(\lambda_1\:\dotsb\:\lambda_n),$$ we have $$f^*(x)=(\lambda_1 \:\: \dotsb \:\: \lambda_n) \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix},$$ a linear combination of the coordinates of $x$, and we can view the linear form $f^*$ as a linear equation. If we decide to use a column vector of coefficients $$ c=\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix}$$ instead of a row vector, then the linear form $f^*$ is defined by $$f^*(x)=c^Tx.$$

from Jean Gallier's text Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory For Computer Science and Machine Learning (freely available online), I instead obtain, for example,
$$v_1^*(v_1)=v_1^*(v_1)*1+ v_1^*(v_2)*0+v_1^*(v_3)*0=1,$$
which gives me no new information. With respect to the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, on the other hand, the text's equation gives me $$v_1^*(v_1)=\left[v_1^*(e_1) \:\:v_1^*(e_2) \: \: v_1^*(e_3)\right] \:v_1=1,$$ which is the correct equation (rightmost equality) to be used in the linear system (where we solve for $v_1^*(e_i)$).
Why does this happen? In other words, why do we get the desired linear system when using the equation from the text with respect to the standard basis and not the given basis?
